# How to know next XML tag in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <employee name = "abc" empId = "100" location = "goa" dept = "IT" />
        <facilities transport="Y" mealcard = "" driver = "Y"/>
        <reportees manager = "XXX" lead = "XXX" VP = "XXX"/>
    <employee name = "XYZ" empId = "101" location = "mombai" dept = "IT" />
        <facilities transport="Y" mealcard = "" driver = "Y"/>
        <reportees manager = "XXX" lead = "XXX" VP = "XXX"/>
    <employee name = "PQA" empId = "102" location = "delhi" dept = "IT" />
        <facilities transport="Y" mealcard = "" driver = "Y"/>
        <reportees manager = "XXX" lead = "XXX" VP = "XXX"/>
```

This is my xml (dummy xml). I want to know the next XML tag while parsing the XML. 
e.g. if currently I'm on "employee" tag then next would be "facilities". 
As I've to process the values according to the xml tags.

I'm using stAX parser, but I didn't see any method which will tell me the next XML tag.

Comment: From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html XMLEventReader provides four methods for iteratively parsing XML streams: ... peek: Returns the event but does not iterate to the next event

Comment: Why not to use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html) Parser ?

Comment: @lexicore yeah I misread, deleted the comment.

Comment: @tgdavies Make it an answer, you'll have my upvote.

Comment: can you show us the code which you referred to as having the employee tag?